# Responsive hamburger/dropdown menu not working in wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

I have a problem with my dropdown menu in a Wordpress website.
Basically, I have integrated the menu with some php code so that I can make use of the wordpress's menu function. However, the menu is visible in the desktop version, it "folds" itself when reducing the width of the screen but it does not perform the dropdown animation and stays static.

Please help me, and thank you very much in advance.

I have tried to move the bootstrap cdns in every order, with the jquery cdn first, and then last, and put them in the header, and then in the footer but they all come up with the same result.
This is on a local host environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?> >
<head>
  <title>
  <?php bloginfo('name');?> |
  <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') :  wp_title(); ?>
  </title>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset')?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>


<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
    </nav>



---------------------------------------------------------------------

    <?php 
        // Register Nav Walker class_alias  
        require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';

        // Theme Support
        if ( ! file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php' ) ) {
        // file does not exist... return an error.
        return new WP_Error( 'class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker-missing', __( 'It appears the class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php file may be missing.', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) );
        } else {
            // file exists... require it.
            require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
        }


        register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'BachusBistroChic' ),
    ) );


    ?>
```

---

Also, it shows an error in the console that it`s missing the popper.js file, but that file is already linked through the bootstrap cdn.

Comment: Try including the `popper.js` file before `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did try that as well but did not work :(